# How to make a string's content appears on screen as we type on keyboard?

Tags: python, string, pygame

I have this function, where player can type his name, but I want each letter to appear on the screen as he types them.
Here is my function :

```
def input_player_name():
    player_name_screen = True
    name = ""
    win.blit(player_name_bg, (0, 0))
    while player_name_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(name)
                    player_name_screen = False
                else:
                    name += event.unicode                 
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

If I write `print(name)`right after `name+=event.unicode`, each thing typed appears in the console. Do I have to use something like this

```
textsurface = game_font.render(str(name), False, (255, 255, 255))
    win.blit(textsurface, (0, 0))
```

and make it update each time something new goes into `name`?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) or [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html). In the following I use 
`pygame.font`.
Waht you have to do is to generate a `font` object and render the text to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) (`name_surf`). This surface has to be `blit` to the window continuously in the loop. When the name changes, the the surface has to be recreated:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.font

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

def input_player_name():
    # create font and text surface
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    name_surf = font.render('', True, (255, 0, 0))
    player_name_screen = True
    name = ""
    while player_name_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    player_name_screen = False
                else:
                    name += event.unicode
                    # recreate text surface   
                    name_surf = font.render(name, True, (255, 0, 0))              

        win.blit(player_name_bg, (0, 0))
        # blit text to window
        win.blit(name_surf, (50, 50))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

input_player_name()
```